# CultureInfo("ar") returns English on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Running this code should yield the Arabic representation of current month and it does on my local machine, however when running on server I always get English.

```
new CultureInfo("ar").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[System.DateTime.Now.Month]
```

At first I suspected it has something to do with request localization hence I tried to just new up a new culture info and see what it outputs, so the above code returns English regardless.

Comment: Maybe there is no Arabic language installed on your server?

Comment: BTW, which server OS do you have? Windows 20xx? Linux?

Comment: @UweKeim It's a docker (linux) container (official core alpine image) and yeah i haven't checked if the language is installed. I might be that dumb though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set of supported cultures is OS specific - you get different sets even between flavors of Windows - desktop and server editions are different, generally with server having less supported cultures. Also the older version of Windows you use smaller list of cultures is supported. The same applies to running .NET core on other OS (including Linux in Kubernetes containers) - it's OS that essentially drives list of supported cultures.

Note that some OS (Windows 10 in particular) will happily provide you with "culture info" for any string you pass - it will try the best to construct something that may make sense (i.e. for "ru-GB" it may try to give "en-GB" culture as the closest one), but for something that has no information whatsoever you likely get invariant/neutral culture (which generally resembles en-US).